# Modify .htaccess to include parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(signup|login|validatesignup|validatelogin|links|stats)/?$ index.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ redirect.php?code=$1
```

Now this basically, redirects anything but the list above to `redirect.php?code=whatever_is_sent`, but whatever is in the list would be redirect to `index.php?page=stats`

Now, some of my pages have GET parameter such as `index.php?page=stats`

Now I basically want `stats&id=1` to be also redirect to `index.php?page=stats&id=1`

But this isn't working

Is this do-able?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(signup|login|validatesignup|validatelogin|links|stats)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ redirect.php?code=$1 [L,QSA]
```

It'll make it so any existing query string parameters get *appended* to the end of the new query string.

Comment: @Ali What's the URL that you're using?